# Unable to pull :page params from the URL on 301 router redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, routes

I am trying to do a **301** redirect in my router from

```
/category?page=2
```

to

```
/category/page/2
```

here is my code

```
get "#{route}(:page)" => redirect {|params,request| "#{params[:name]}/#{route}/page/#{params[:page]" }
```

It almost works except that the last `params[:page]` translates to `nil`. So I get

```
/category/page/
```

Tried `:page` and `(:page)` - these do not work
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like you want on rails 4.2.4

`get :category, to: redirect { |params, request| "/category/#{request.params[:page]}/"}`

If you need to pass the query parameters just add `request.params.to_query` at the end ;)